# AlarmManager, pass an object

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-broadcastreceiver

I need to build notification with delay.
I've created a class:

```
public class Schedule extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Notification.Builder notificationBuilder;
    int delayMinutes;
    String bigText;
    int NOTIFY_ID;

    public Schedule(Notification.Builder notificationBuilderIn, int delayMinutesIn, String bigTextIn, int NOTIFY_ID_IN) {
        //code.
    }

    public Schedule() {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //code with imported objects.
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context) {
        //code
    }
```

And this to Manifest:

```
<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".Schedule" />
```

And this thing requires a default constructor for Schedule class.
If I remove default constructor, app crashes.

I pass data like this:

```
Schedule schedule = new Schedule(builder, delay, bigText, NOTIFY_ID);
schedule.setAlarm(this);
```

But it does not work as it calls only default constructor, ignoring my overload.

How to fix it or store objects like values in SharedPreferences?

Comment: Well, I've found a workaround, but what if I will ever need to do this? Question is still active. Workaround was simple - build notification in the method itself.